# Process finished with exit code 1 when stopping Embedded Undertow

Tags: java, undertow

In my application I start embedded *Undertow* in program main method. In all tutorials `stop` method is not used. If I run appliction from terminal or from *IntelliJ* and stop it (*CTRL+C* or stop icon) I see

> Process finished with exit code 1

I tried adding

```
Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(undertow::stop));
```

but result is the same.

Where should I call `stop` method?

Comment: `server.stop()` shall work for you, *where* could be defined looking at more context of how actually you start the server and perform execution.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a [sample builder api](http://undertow.io/undertow-docs/undertow-docs-1.3.0/index.html#the-builder-api) which can be altered(just a sample) to stop after performing a console logging as:

```
public class HelloWorldServer {

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        Undertow server = Undertow.builder()                                                    //Undertow builder
                .addListener(8080, "localhost")                                                 //Listener binding
                .setHandler(new HttpHandler() {                                                 //Default Handler
                    @Override
                    public void handleRequest(final HttpServerExchange exchange) throws Exception {
                        exchange.getResponseHeaders().put(Headers.CONTENT_TYPE, "text/plain");  //Response Headers
                        exchange.getResponseSender().send("Hello World");                       //Response Sender
                    }
                }).build();
        server.start();
        System.out.println("I did some work for you..Rest is to dig deeper!");
        server.stop();
    }

}
```